# Issue with deploying Azure function docker image using Github Actions

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-functions

During the following step in my GitHub action

```
- name: 'Run Azure Functions Container Action'
  uses: Azure/functions-container-action@v1.2.0
  with:
    app-name: my_app_name
    image: my_image_name
```

The action never ends up completed even after waiting several minutes. I am getting the following logs on the GitHub action:

```
Run Azure/functions-container-action@v1.2.0
Updating App Service Configuration settings. Data: 
Updated App Service Configuration settings.
Restarting app service: my_app_name
Deployment passed
Restarted app service: my_app_name
Warning: Failed to sync function triggers in function app. Trigger listing may be out of date.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to possibly solve this or what may be causing the issue? I am able to run and use the docker image locally perfectly fine. It's just I am currently unable to deploy the image to azure using GitHub actions. If it makes a difference the azure function is made in python. I was following the following repo https://github.com/Azure/functions-container-action

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message and where it originates from in the [code](https://github.com/Azure/functions-container-action/blob/master/src/main.ts#L43), it is likely that your function app is failing to start.

You should check the [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) and look out for any missing application settings as well.